# Spanning a finite vector space using different powers of a diagonalizable matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

D be an n x n real diagonal matrix. show that there exists a x $\epsilon$ $\Bbb R$$^n$ such that

span{D$^k$x: 0$\le$k$\le$(n-1)} = $\Bbb R$$^n$

if and only if the eigenvalues of D are distinct.

I can show that if D has distinct eigenvalues then $\Bbb R$$^n$ isa direct sum of n eigenspaces and I can find the required x such that the condition holds, but i am unable to prove it the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get $\mathbb{R}^n$ from $\mathrm{span}\{D^kx\,:\,0\leq k\leq (n-1)\},$ it is obvious that the vector space $\mathrm{span}\{D^k\,:\,0\leq k\leq (n-1)\}\subset \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ must have dimension of at least $n.$ However, in case of a diagonalizable matrix $D$, the minimal polynomial of $D$ is $\mu(t) = \prod_{k=1}^{r}(t-\lambda_k),$ where the $\lambda_k$ are the $r$ distinct eigenvalues of $D.$ So if you have less than $n$ distinct eigenvalues in a diagonalizable matrix $D$, the minimal polynomial of $D$ will have a degree of less than $n$, and the expression $\mu(D)=0$ forms a non-trivial linear combination of the $(r+1)$ elements $D^0,\,D^1,\ldots,\,D^r$ with the result of $0.$ This shows that the basis of $\mathrm{span}\{D^k\,:\,0\leq k\leq (n-1)\}$ can have at most $r$ elements (using the identity $\mu(D)=0$ we can write $D^{r},\, D^{r+1},\dots,\,D^{n-1}$ as linear combinations of $D^0,\,\ldots,\,D^{r-1}$), which means that $\mathrm{span}\{D^kx\,:\,0\leq k\leq (n-1)\}$ can have a dimension of at most $r.$